# It is possible to gain Caucus for elections in the notstarted phase

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, election

Caucus is a badge that can be awarded multiple times for visiting "an election during any phase of an *active* election and have enough reputation to cast a vote." Who wrote the description likely meant "active" as in "that isn't ended yet", but the badge can be [awarded](https://askubuntu.com/badges/107/caucus?userid=1938) also for [elections that aren't *started* yet.](https://askubuntu.com/election/3)

Comment: I just visited [Ask Ubuntu's upcoming election](http://askubuntu.com/election/3) and sure enough [I gained the Caucus badge](http://askubuntu.com/badges/107/caucus?userid=75668), though the election is showing in the `notstarted` phase.

Comment: @MichaelHampton that is exactly what got me to post this bug report to begin with :-)

Comment: [Ah, right...](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2234?m=5977116#5977116).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few of you received this badge early but it will not happen after the next build.  If you got your badge early hopefully you'll be a good citizen and vote anyway when the time comes.

Comment: Gah, more voting? You guys want me to vote on *everything* around here!

Comment: @mikeTheLiar It's how they can justify pretending that anything we say has any bearing on reality on Stack Exchange! Conspiracy!

Comment: @Lightness upvoting your comment because voting.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar upvoting your comment because election fraud